# Running commands on a remote machine

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the best solution for sending commands to a remote computer. This is for automated testing on remote machines, however - it is for a Windows based app so all the support for web based testing we can not use.

What I want is a way to send commands that look for certain file paths in a remote machine and the ability to run taskkill commands as well. What is the best way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: maybe be powershell?

Comment: winrm, sysinternals psrun